# How to select records with minutes interval range of current day and time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have columns:

date = "2017-12-10" (type = date)

time = "14:10:00" (type = time)

duration = "40" (type = varchar 100)

For example, today date is "2017-12-10" and today time is "14:30". How can I get records only for current time and only in time interval "40 minutes"? So accepted time range would be "14:10:00-14:50:00".

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT date, time, duration FROM events WHERE date = CURDATE() AND time >= CURTIME();
```

But it doesn't search in 40 minutes interval.

Thank you.

Comment: Store date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this?

```
SELECT date, time, duration FROM events WHERE date = CURDATE() AND time between date_add(CURTIME(), interval -duration minutes) and CURTIME();
```

Comment: Could you tell me how can I make this logic "date_add(CURTIME(), interval -duration-20 minutes)"? For example if I want 20 minutes more.

Answer (score 1):

I thought your problem required a need for +/-(duration/2)

```
select
      date_sub(CONCAT(dt, " ", tim), interval ( cast(duration as unsigned) / 2 ) minute) st
    , date_add(CONCAT(dt, " ", tim), interval ( cast(duration as unsigned) / 2 ) minute) fin
    , d.*
from (
    select curdate() as dt, cast('14:10:00' as time) as tim, '40' as duration union all
    select curdate() as dt, cast('14:10:00' as time) as tim, '60' as duration union all
    select curdate() as dt, cast('14:10:00' as time) as tim, '90' as duration
    ) d
where
    CONCAT(dt, " ", tim) between date_sub(CONCAT(dt, " ", tim), interval ( cast(duration as unsigned) / 2 ) minute) 
                             and date_add(CONCAT(dt, " ", tim), interval ( cast(duration as unsigned) / 2 ) minute)
```

Comment: revised the query so you see the approach as both a select and as where clause predicates